# How to filter a list and pick randomly one of the resulting records in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, list

I want to randomly pick a name that matches specific criteria. See for example the image:

[image]

How can I filter a list, each one with associated data in other columns, using provided criteria, then pick randomly one record?

I can use VB if needed, I'm not restricted to formulas in cells.

Comment: Do you mean "How to randomly filter a list based on multiple criteria in Excel?" || coz the title said "filtered" but "how can I filter.." & "Randomly picking a cell among a simple array is easy.." is in the question body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best result so far is:

- Data -> enable filter on the list
- set the filtering criteria using VBA:

  `Sheets(mySheet).Range(myRange).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & myValue`
- copy only visible cells to another place:

  `Sheets(mySheet).Range(myRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
  Sheets(myNewSheet).Range(myNewRange).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues`
- pick a random cell from the resulting list:

  `=INDEX('myNewSheet'!myNewRange;RANDBETWEEN(1;COUNTA('myNewSheet'!myNewRange)))`